# i am trying to create a get request using axios library , from one application to another application . i have described it below

Tags: node.js, api, rest, axios, request-headers

```
 const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'correlation-id': requestContextGet('correlationId'),
          };
```

This is my header and it is showing an error when i tried to make a get call using postman .

```
ERROR: BadRequestError: request size did not match content length
```

The following get call is made from one application to another application .
after reachhing application it should enter this method

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.is('text/plain')) {
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    const inflatedData = inflate(
      new Uint8Array([...base64Decode(req.body)].map((c) => c.charCodeAt(0)))
    );
    const decodedData = decoder.decode(inflatedData);
    req.body = JSON.parse(decodedData);
  }
  next();
});
```

but it is not even entering this method .